# How to Group all property option in Array of Objects

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

i wnat to get the type of array in some property
and get autocomplate by typescript typing

```js
const arr = [{test:'option 1'},{test: 'option 2'}]
type test = arr[number]['test']
let t:test = '' // will equal 'option 1' or 'option 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast **arr** to const, so typescript can infer its type correctly, e.g.

```
const arr = [{test:'option 1'},{test: 'option 2'}] as const; // <-- cast to const here
type test = typeof arr[number]['test'];
let t:test = ''; // will equal 'option 1' or 'option 2'
```

Comment: Thanks :) good job